# Free Microsoft Visio for Education - Mac User

Tags: software

I need a Microsoft Visio-like tool that works on a Mac and is free for educational users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about software recommendation. Maybe on topic in softwarerecs.SE

Comment: Hi Tyler, you may ask this question again in Software Recommendation of StackExchange, there are lots of experts in that forum. I had asked a few questions on that Software Recommendation and I got some useful answers from the people there.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/) (full disclosure: I work for Lucid Software, the maker of Lucidchart). They do support Visio import and export. Just got a good write up on [Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/309297/lucidchart-replaces-visio-on-mac/).

Comment: Thanks for the full disclosure. In my opinion, you did this right: mention the affiliation and make sure that your answer appropriately addresses the question.